# Why are all tags un-capitalised?

Tags: discussion, tags

This seems self-explanatory but I noticed when looking through the questions, that all of the tags don't have capitals at the beginning.
I don't mean to sound pedantic but shouldn't they have capital letters?
(If there is a reason they are left as they are, then I'm happy to hear it?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [Is there any reason why tags are lower-cased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216225/is-there-any-reason-why-tags-are-lower-cased) on Meta.StackExchange:

> Lower-case tags have several advantages:
>
> - Prevents people accidentally creating two tags that differ only in capitalisation, whether intentional or otherwise.*
> - Prevents arguments over the correct capitalisation
> - Creates a consistent look and feel
>
> I think for these reasons alone, it was sensible to opt for lower-case tags.

The system only allows to create tags in lowercase, which is why all tags are lowercase. There are some advantages to this approach and not really any downsides.

From the [privilege page about *Create Tags*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

> - must use the character set `a-z` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.`